# Removing gap in width (make it 100%) of HMTL5 video embedding using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video

After trying out several options, I managed to embed a video in the home page (just like in airbnb). Now that I don't get to close the small gap that is appearing in the edge of video and browser. 
Checking in both safari and chrome the gap is in the width.

```
            <!DOCTYPE div PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>World wonders</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <style type="text/css">
                h3{
                    color: #3cbc8d;
                    z-index: 1;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-top: 10%;
                    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
                    padding: 10px;
                    border-radius: 15px;
                    width: 700px;
                    letter-spacing: 3px;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                }
                .header-container{
                    width:100%;
                    height:478px;
                    border-left:none;
                    border-right:none;
                    position: relative;
                    padding: 20px;
                    border:1px solid redred;
                    background-color:black;
                    z-index: -2;        
                }

                .video-container{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    width:100%;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    border:1px solid red;
                    background-color:black;
                    z-index: -2;        
                }

                video{
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: -1;
                    opacity: 0.98;
                    width: 100%;
                    border:1px solid blue;
                }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="header-container">
                    <div class="video-container embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video class="embed-responsive-item" preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="" volume="0" muted poster="pic.jpg">
                            <source src="../media/bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="../media/bbb.webm" type="video/webm">
                            <source src="../media/bbb.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Welcome to the world of wonders</h3>
                </div> <!-- header container div-->
            </body>
            </html>
```

How can I ensure the video stays full width in all browsers?

Comment: HTML code is added along with the question. Is it visible to you?

Comment: Ok I think I know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Place a padding on the left and right of the .header-container. `padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;`. Have a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91seLqzz/3/). If you wanted the text to remain at the top, remove the position:absolute in h3, and change it to relative.

Comment: Let me know if this is what you requested .

Comment: I tried your solution, but I find a white space on the top. I would need to avoid gap on top and both sides (width) but height would need to be adjustable.

Comment: You mean the black bit at the top?

Comment: Not the black of video. Between the video and the top of the browser, there is space (means its a tad bit down from the top of  browser)

Comment: For some reason, I don't see it working in browser. tried safari and chrome. The difference is huge in chrome. but i can see fiddle it is coming as expected!